# Passing ng-repeat context to child directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

In parts of my application I have used a directive in this format:

```
<child-directive ng-repeat="item in vm.items"></child-directive>
```

This one has access to `{{item}}` from within `child-directive` without having to do anything.

Now I want to use the same directive along side other directives that all work with the same context data:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in vm.items">
  <child-directive></child-directive>
  <other-directive></other-directive>
</div>
```

The child directive does not need to alter the context data, it only needs the information from inside to display a widget.

I've tried using `scope` in the directive in this format:

```
angular
    .module('myapp.dashboard')
    .directive('childDirective', childDirective);

function childDirective() {
    var directive = {
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl: 'client/components/child-directive.ng.html',
      controller: 'ChildDirectiveController',
      controllerAs: 'vm',
      scope: {
        item: '='
      }
    };

    return directive;
}
```

and

```
<child-directive ng-attr-item="{{item}}"></child-directive>
```

Within the `ng-repeat` section. However that just throws an error.

I've also tried `ng-bind` with no luck.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `<child-directive="item in vm.items"></child-directive>` is invalid HTML, are you sure you didn't mean `<child-directive ng-repeat="item in vm.items"></child-directive>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using bi-directional scope binding rather than an interpolated property. You can read up on this more [in the angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-)

Change your scope object to be:

```
scope: {
  item: '@'
}
```

**OR**, change your template to:

```
<child-directive ng-attr-item="item"></child-directive>
```

Comment: If `item` is an object will this still work as an interpolated property? It seems to throw the whole object as JSON in the property.

Comment: Nope, if item is an object you should use the bi-directional-assignment method you have and just remove the curly braces from your param.

Comment: I'll give that a shot now.